# Where to perform an asynchronous transform of existing state in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working on a React/Redux application, and I'm struggling with how to structure the code for an asynchronous data transform.

I have part of the state tree which is stored as a plain javascript object; this is data that is requested asynchronously from an API, and used throughout the application.  When the user clicks a button, I want to transform that existing state from JSON to CSV, and feed it as a prop to an anchor tag for download.

Normally I would do this in a selector, but the JSON to CSV conversion is asynchronous.  I could store the entire CSV string on the state tree using an async action creator, but that feels redundant.

Is there a pattern for doing asynchronous transforms of existing state?  Is there something fundamental that I'm missing?  I've looked at libraries like [async-selector](https://github.com/humflelump/async-selector), but I can't shake the feeling that I'm fighting the tooling, and not seeing something obvious.  Any suggestions?